# What's the derivative of $f(x)=(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3})^{\sin(2x)}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of $f(x)=(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3})^{\sin(2x)}$ using the difference quotient but somehow I don't succeed.

Help and elegant solution appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Take the logarithm on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\log f(x) = \sin(2x) \log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)$$
$$\begin{align} \implies f'(x) &= f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin(2x) \log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)\right]\\&=\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)^{\sin(2x)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin(2x) \log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)\right]\end{align}$$
I will now focus on the remaining derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sin(2x) \log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)\right]$$
$$=\left[2\cos(2x) \log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)+\sin(2x)\frac{d}{dx}\log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)\right]$$
If we now just focus on the logarithm; using the substitution $u=\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}$ we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log\left(\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$=\frac{x^2 + 3}{x^2 + 1} \frac{4 x}{(x^2+3)^2}$$
$$=\frac{4 x}{(x^2 + 1)(x^2+3)}$$

Comment: That's exactly as far as I managed to solve this :(

Comment: @user305938 XD I can go further. In the future, please post what you have tried so far... it saves time and helps people tailor better answers!

Comment: @user305938 Did you try applying the product rule here?

Comment: Yes but I have problems with the derivative of log

Comment: that would be great brevan!

Comment: $sin(2x)*[log(x^2+1)-log(x^2+3)]$, and derivative of $log(x^2+1)$ is $2x\over x^2+1$

Comment: but that's only a part of the solution right?

Comment: @user305938 What Shrey is suggesting is that you break up the derivative of logarithm into two derivatives, each being a bit simpler. I updated my answer with a slightly different method though, that doesn't break up the logarithms (does require the quotient rule though, which is effectively a shortcut for the product rule)

Comment: @user305938 My answer should now have all the pieces you need to form your final answer, with a bit of simplification here and there